# I can't append an svg element returned by a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to insert an svg element returned by a function, without success. What am I doing wrong? Here is the code:

```
let svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")

function blackLine() {
    let line = d3.create("line")
        .attr("x1", 100)
        .attr("x2", 500)
        .attr("y1", 50)
        .attr("y2", 50)
        .attr("stroke", "black");
    return line.node();
}

function draw(){
    svg.append(blackLine);
    svg.append("line")
        .attr("x1", 100)
        .attr("x2", 500)
        .attr("y1", 100)
        .attr("y2", 50)
        .attr("stroke", "red");
}

draw();
```

In the browser I can see the red line, but not the black one. The line is there though: if I inspect the rendered page, I see:
[Image of svg DOM in the browser debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00Txx.png)

And if I edit as HTML any field of the black svg line (say change the y2 attribute to 70), the line appears!

It looks like a bug to me, but I may do something wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: The only thing missing is the namespace: `let line = d3.create("svg:line")`.

Comment: OH, THANK YOU. It was written in the doc and I didn't see it :-)  . Last line of example in the D3 manual : d3.create("g") // an HTML G (**unknown**) element